# No member named 'format' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++

При попытке использования '**format**', выходит ошибка:

> No member named 'format' in namespace 'std'

Работаю на macbook air M2. Пробовал запускать в *xcode* и в *vscode*, нигде не работает. Что я делаю не так ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
 
int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("Hello {}!\n", "world");
}
```

Comment: Версия Xcode 14.2 || 
Версия Clang 14.0.0 || 
macOs Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: `std::format()` появился начиная с C++20. Может стандарт более старый?

Comment: Я думал об этом, но как это проверить, а тем более исправить я вообще понятия не имею. Вроде как Xcode этой версии должен поддерживать данный стандарт.

Comment: В VSCode выбрать расширение C/C++, настройки, там будет настройка `C_Cpp > Default: Cpp Standart`. Для XCode - не знаю, поиск в помощь.

Comment: @NolReaction А это влияет на что-то, кроме IntelliSense?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71777564/cant-use-stdformat-in-c20 В libstdc++, используемый в macOs  данная функция не реализована.

Comment: @Chorkov спасибо за ответ !

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо ***@Chorkov***. В libstdc++, используемый в macOs данная функция не реализована